# Como fazer esse efeito com CSS

Tags: css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso fazer aqueles cantos na `div` do rodapé.

Tentei fazer o esquema dos triângulos usando `pseudo-element`, mas não consegui.

```
border-top: 30px solid @Laranja;
border-right: 30px transparent @Laranja;
border-left: 30px transparent @Laranja;
```

Tem alguma maneira ?

Comment: Algo assim serviria ? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp

Comment: Mas ela não é redonda, é quadrada. Não tem um `border-square` ?

Comment: Achei alguns parecidos, mas nada como você quer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: Já tentou criar um elemento para cada ponta e rotacionar alguns graus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilize gradientes CSS:

```css
div {
    background: orange; /* fallback */
    background:
        -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, orange 10px),
        -moz-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, orange 10px);
    background:
        -o-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, orange 10px),
        -o-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, orange 10px);
    background:
        -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, orange 10px),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, orange 10px);
}



div {
    background-position: top right, top left;
    -moz-background-size: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


div {
    float:left;
    margin:15px auto;
    padding:15px;
    color: white;
    line-height:1.5;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div style='width:95%'>Div 1</div>
```

Fonte:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770312/how-to-achieve-chamfered-css-border-corners-rather-than-rounded-corners

Comment: Eu preciso sem a parte debaixo. Só a parte de cima com esses cantos.

Comment: @DeeSouza basta remover os backgrounds posicionados nos cantos inferiores. Eu editei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

É mais fácil utilizar SVG do que tentar fazer tudo com CSS.

```css
polygon { fill: #F7941D }
text    { fill: #000    }
```

```html
<svg width='600' height='200'>
  <g>
    <polygon points='0,20 20,0 580,0 600,20 600,180 600,200 0,200 0,180'/>
    <text x='245' y='110'>StackOverflow</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

O atributo `points` da tag [`<polygon>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon) representam as coordenadas no eixo *x* e *y*, respectivamente. [Nesse link](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_polygon.asp) da W3Cshool existem alguns exemplos do que é possível fazer definindo as coordenadas de um polígono.

Para incluir um texto, pode usar a tag [`<text>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text).

Comment: Certo, mas tem como eu por conteúdo texto aí dentro desse SVG ?

Comment: Esse tipo de coisa é bom você incluir enquanto está perguntando, até porque você só pediu a imagem. São perguntas diferentes, mas vou editar a minha resposta.